# Elasticsearch-Connector: can't index with Search-API

Tags: search

Im using latest Drupal 8.x with Search-API 8.x-1.5 und Elasticsearch_Connector 8.x-5.0alpha1.

I can add a cluster and via Search API I can also connect to the Elasticsearch Server. But when I try to add an Index via Search API the following error comes up:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [id]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [id]"},"status":400}
```

Does anyone know of such an error and can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch has deprecated the `string` type in 5.x versions, and is now using `text` or `keyword`. (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/string.html)

In **/admin/config/search/search-api/`<CLUSTER>`/`<INDEX>`/fields**, you may change `string` by `text` in ID field. Considering this is an integer -id-, you may choose the type `integer`.